# How to handle this kind of non-linear constraint in the optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have an optimization problem where I have following constraint which is causing problem in converting the problem into a convex optimization problem. The constraint is given as follows $$g\geq \frac{1}{a+\|\textbf{x}\|^2}$$ where $\textbf{x}$ is a two dimensional column vector and $a>0$ is a constant. In this constraint the optimization variables are $g$ and $\textbf{x}$. I do not know how to convexify this constraint. I think if I can find a convex upper bound of $$\frac{1}{a+\|\textbf{x}\|^2}$$ then the above constraint can be converted into a convex set. However, I do not know how to get the convex upper bound of $\frac{1}{a+\|\textbf{x}\|^2}$. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $a>0$, then your problem is already convex: (1) $x\mapsto (a+\|x\|^2)^{-1}$ is convex, and (2) $g\mapsto -g$ is also convex. Altogether, $F\colon (x,g)\mapsto (a+\|x\|^2)^{-1}-g$ is a convex function and your constraint is just $\{(x,g)|F(x,g)\leq 0\}$. What am I missing here?

Comment: From Frank's comment on another question, I think he may be interested in solving the problem using an MM method.  He'd like to find a separable quadratic function that majorizes $1/(a+\| x \|^{2})$. @FrankMoses if that's your question then please clarify it.

Comment: @BrianBorchers yes that is the goal to get a convex approximation of $\frac{1}{a+\|\textbf{x}\|^2}$. But in your comment to the other question you said that $\frac{1}{a+\|\textbf{x}\|^2}$ is not a convex function but Max_Zorn is saying that its a convex function. I am confused.

Comment: @BrianBorchers please note that $a>0$ in my problem.

Comment: @max_zorn : It appears that $x$ is a vector, so the function $f(x)=1/(a+||x||^2)$ is not convex.  For example, for $f(x_1,x_2)=1/(1+||x||^2)$ we can compare $x=(0,1)$, $y=(1,0)$, $z=(1/2)x + (1/2)y=(1/2,1/2)$ and then $$ \frac{1}{2}f(x) + \frac{1}{2}f(y) = 1/2 < 2/3 = f(z)$$

Comment: Your function is certainly not convex in general.  Take $a=1$, and consider the line from $x=(-1,0)$ through $x=(0,0)$ to $x=(1,0)$.  Along this line, $f(x)$ goes from $1/2$ to $1$ and back to $1/2$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers yes I understand it. So is there a way to convert the above constraint into a convex set? Through whichever method.

Comment: In the MM method for a minimization problem, we find a convex majorizing function for the objective $f(x)$ that is being minimized.  You haven't described a problem in this form.  Please go back and clearly state your problem.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Is there any other way around?

Comment: You haven't told us what your actual problem is, thus your question can't be answered.  I've voted close as "unclear what you're asking."

Comment: @BrianBorchers I do not have any knowledge about the MM methods. So I do not know how to write my problem in that format.

Comment: I made a mistake, $x\mapsto 1/(a+\|x\|^2)$ is not convex. Unfortunately, its *convexification* is the $x\mapsto 0$, which is not very helpful.

Comment: @max_zorn ok I understand that it is not a convex function. Is there a way to handle such constraint?